# HTTParty won't load in Ruby file

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, httparty

I am trying to run a webscraper and when I execute the file I get the following error

```
/home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)
    from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from luismejia71lbs.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I have HTTParty installed and even ran sudo gem install httparty a few times just in case. Not sure why it won't run and I can't find anything concrete. I recently installed rbenv in the last week, not sure if that is related, but since I was able to run httparty in the past.

Here is my file

webscraper.rb

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pry'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

craigslist = HTTParty.get('https://miami.craigslist.org/search/mdc/apa?min_bedrooms=3&max_bedrooms=3&min_bathrooms=2&max_bathrooms=2&availabilityMode=0')
Pry.start.(binding)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means rbenv can't find the httparty gem. Since rbenv installs gems under ~/.rbenv, you shouldn't need the `sudo` command to install httparty. Using `sudo` will almost certainly install in the wrong place. Just do:

```
$ gem install httparty
```